# UpdateItemEnhancedRequest ignoreNulls not Working for Nested Beans

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-enhanced-client

I have a DynamoDbBean with a nested DynamoDbBean

```
@DynamoDbBean
public class OuterBean {
    private String Id;
    private InnerBean innerBean;

    public OuterBean() {
        
    }

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute(value = "Id")
    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    @DynamoDbIgnoreNulls
    @DynamoDbAttribute(value = "innerBean")
    public InnerBean getInnerBean() {
        return innerBean;
    }

    public void setInnerBean(@Nullable InnerBean innerBean) {
        this.innerBean = innerBean;
    }
}

@DynamoDbBean
public class InnerBean {
    private Integer field1;
    private Integer field2;

    public Integer getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(Integer field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public Integer getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(Integer field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

I would like to update `field1` in a record's `InnerBean` section only, without modifying any of the other properties in an `OuterBean` record or its `InnerBean` section. I'm unable to do this using an `UpdateItemEnhancedRequest`.

```
        DynamoDbEnhancedClient client = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(
                        DynamoDbClient.builder()
                                .region(Region.of("us-east-1"))
                                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                                .build())
                .build();

        DynamoDbTable<OuterBean> table = client.table(caseTableName, TableSchema.fromBean(OuterBean.class));

        OuterBean outerBean = new OuterBean();
        outerBean.setId("1");

        InnerBean innerBean = new InnerBean();
        innearBean.setField1(1);
        // Notice field2 is null

        outerBean.setInnerBean(innerBean);

        table.updateItem(
                UpdateItemEnhancedRequest
                        .builder(OuterBean.class)
                        .item(outerBean)
                        .ignoreNulls(true)
                        .build()
        );
```

Despite using `ignoreNulls` and `@DynamoDbIgnoreNulls`, I still see the record's `field2` property get set to null in the database table instead of being ignored.

How can I ignore null values of nested beans?